# Using AngularFire2 to query collections

Tags: database, angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm building an Ionic 2 app using AngularFire 2 to communicate with Firebase.

Here is my Firebase database:

```
    {
    "films" : [
        {
            "title" : "John Wick",
            "summary": "Ex-assassin John Wick takes down the Russian Mafia after being violenty attacked by Russian thugs in his home after the death of his wife",
            "date" : "2014",
            "duration": "97 minutes",
            "rating": "15",
            "cover" : "none",
            "actors" : {
                "keanureeves" : true,
                "willemdafoe" : true,
                "michaelnyqvist" : true,
                "ianmcshane" : true,
                "johnleguizamo" : true,
                "bridgetmoynahan" : true,
                "alfieallen" : true,
                "adriannepalicki" : true
            },
            "genres" : {
                "action" : true,
                "thriller" : true
            },
            "images" : {
               "image1" : true,
               "image2" : true,
               "image3" : true,
               "image4" : true,
               "image5" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "title" : "Gladiator",
            "summary": "The general who became a slave, the slave who became a gladiator, the gladiator who defied an empire",
            "date" : "2000",
            "duration": "2hr 29 minutes",
            "rating": "15",
            "cover" : "none",
            "actors" : {
                "russellcrowe" : true,
                "oliverreed" : true
            },
            "genres" : {
                "action" : true
            },
            "images" : {
               "image6" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "title" : "Catch me if you can",
            "summary": "Frank Abagnale Jr, master of deception",
            "date" : "2002",
            "duration": "135 minutes",
            "rating": "12",
            "cover" : "none",
            "actors" : {
                "tomhanks" : true,
                "leonardodicaprio" : true,
                "christopherwalken" : true
            },
            "genres" : {
                "comedy" : true,
                "thriller" : true
            },
            "images" : {
               "image7" : true,
               "image8" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "title" : "Street Kings",
            "summary": "Corrupt, murderous cops in Los Angeles",
            "date" : "2008",
            "duration": "104 minutes",
            "rating": "15",
            "cover" : "none",
            "actors" : {
                "forestwhitaker" : true,
                "keanureeves" : true,
                "chrisevans" : true
            },
            "genres" : {
                "crime" : true,
                "action" : true,
                "thriller" : true
            },
            "images" : {
               "image9" : true
            }
        }
    ],


    "images" : {
      "image1" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Keanu Reeves as John Wick"
      },
      "image2" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Taking down the Russian mafia"
      },
      "image3" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Nightclub scene #1"
      },
      "image4" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Nightclub scene #2"
      },
      "image5" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Nightclub scene #3"
      },
      "image6" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Maximus the Gladiator"
      },
      "image7" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Leonardo DiCaprio as Frank Abagnale Jr"
      },
      "image8" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Panam-Air hostesses"
      },
      "image9" : {
         "image" : "ref",
         "caption": "Keanu reeves as Detective Tom Ludlow"
      }
    },


    "actors" : {
        "keanureeves" : {
           "name" : "Keanu reeves",
           "nationality" : "Canadian"
        },
        "willemdafoe" : {
           "name" : "Willem Dafoe",
           "nationality" : "Dutch"
        },
        "michaelnyqvist" :  {
           "name" : "Michael Nyqvist",
           "nationality" : "Swedish"
        },
        "ianmcshane" : {
           "name" : "Ian McShane",
           "nationality" : "English"
        },
        "johnleguizamo" : {
           "name" : "John Leguizamo",
           "nationality" : "Colombian-American"
        },
        "bridgetmoynahan" : {
           "name" : "Bridget Moynahan",
           "nationality" : "American"
        },
        "alfieallen" : {
           "name" : "Alfie Allen",
           "nationality" : "English"
        },
        "adiannepalicki" : {
           "name" : "Adrianne Palicki",
           "nationality" : "American"
        },
        "russellcrowe" : {
           "name" : "Russell Crowe",
           "nationality" : "New Zealander"
        },
        "oliverreed" : {
           "name" : "Oliver Reed",
           "nationality" : "English"
        },
        "leonardodicaprio" : {
           "name" : "Leonardo DiCaprio",
           "nationality" : "American"
        },
        "tomhanks" : {
           "name" : "Tom Hanks",
           "nationality" : "American"
        },
        "christopherwalken" : {
           "name" : "Christopher Walken",
           "nationality" : "American"
        },
        "martinsheen" : {
           "name" : "Martin Sheen",
           "nationality" : "American"
        },
        "forestwhitaker" : {
           "name" : "Forest Whitaker",
           "nationality" : "American"
        },
        "chrisevans" : {
           "name" : "Chris Evans",
           "nationality" : "American"
        }
    },

    "genres" : {
        "action" : {
            "title": "Action/Adventure"
        },
        "fantasy" : {
            "title": "Fantasy"
        },
        "horror" : {
            "title": "Horror"
        },
        "comedy" : {
            "title": "Comedy"
        },
        "thriller" : {
            "title": "Thriller"
        },
        "sciencefiction" : {
            "title": "Science Fiction"
        },
        "war" : {
            "title": "War"
        },
        "crime" : {
            "title": "Crime"
        },
        "documentary" : {
            "title": "Documentary"
        }      
    }
}
```

I've denormalised the data into specific collections to avoid redundancy/duplication etc (as per best practice suggestions from Firebase).

Please disregard the ref values in the images collection as these are there purely as placeholders for the moment :)

Here is my home.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
   public movies : FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

   constructor(public navCtrl  : NavController,
               public angFire  : AngularFire) 
   {

      this.movies = angFire.database.list('/movies/films');
   }
}
```

Here I use AngularFire 2 to retrieve the films collection as a list.

The films collection also contains the keys to link data to the genres, actors and images collections too.

And my home.html file is structured as follows:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>   
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let movie of movies | async">
         <h2>{{ movie.title }}</h2>         
         <p>{{ movie.duration }}</p>
         <p>{{ movie.date }}</p>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

I can retrieve the films collection and display each film in the component view without problem.

What I want to do however is retrieve data from the actors collection based on the indexes in the actors node for each record in the films collection.

So using each key in this node of a record from the films collection:

```
"actors" : {
   "keanureeves" : true,
   "willemdafoe" : true,
   "michaelnyqvist" : true,
   "ianmcshane" : true,
   "johnleguizamo" : true,
   "bridgetmoynahan" : true,
   "alfieallen" : true,
   "adriannepalicki" : true
},
```

To retrieve the matching data, by supplied key, from the actors collection:

```
"actors" : {
   "keanureeves" : {
      "name" : "Keanu reeves",
      "nationality" : "Canadian"
   },
   "willemdafoe" : {
      "name" : "Willem Dafoe",
      "nationality" : "Dutch"
   },
   "michaelnyqvist" :  {
      "name" : "Michael Nyqvist",
      "nationality" : "Swedish"
   },
   "ianmcshane" : {
      "name" : "Ian McShane",
      "nationality" : "English"
   },
   "johnleguizamo" : {
      "name" : "John Leguizamo",
      "nationality" : "Colombian-American"
   },
   "bridgetmoynahan" : {
      "name" : "Bridget Moynahan",
      "nationality" : "American"
   },
   "alfieallen" : {
      "name" : "Alfie Allen",
      "nationality" : "English"
   },
   "adiannepalicki" : {
      "name" : "Adrianne Palicki",
      "nationality" : "American"
   }
}
```

Does that make sense?

I'm trying to figure out how I would accomplish this.

I've been searching all over the internet for the past few hours but everything I've tried hasn't worked.

I can query an individual collection but I want to, essentially, make a relational query that uses indexes from the films collection to retrieve matching records from the actors, genres and images collections too.

Is there a way to use AngularFire 2 to retrieve the data from different collections based on specific keys and return that in one call?

Comment: short answer is no...  i would suggest looking at the [video series on Firebase and SQL](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=firebase+sql&page=&utm_source=opensearch)